# Can't get javascript, JQuery to work with my PHP

Tags: javascript, php, file

Really nooby question, but couldn't find it on this site, and just can't get it to work.

How can I get javascript and jquery to work when putting CDN into headers / footers?
My javascript is working when I include the CDN and the  tags right in with the HTML, but I want to have my javascript on other pages, rather than in with the HTML view pages.

I can't see what is wrong. Maybe you can help?

this is working

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="caption">Event Description</label>
                            <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/12.3.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
                             <textarea class="form-control" name="event_description" id="body" cols="30" rows="20"></textarea>
                             <script>
                                ClassicEditor
                                    .create( document.querySelector( '#body' ) )
                                    .catch( error => {
                                        console.error( error );
                                    } );
                                </script>
                          </div>
```

However this is not

I have

```
<?php require_once("includes/header.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

on all tops and bottom of HTML view pages.

Here are my headers and footers

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php require_once("init.php"); ?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SB Admin - Bootstrap Admin Template</title>



    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
```

footer

```
  </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->

    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>



    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->

     <!-- jQuery -->

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <!-- WYSIWYG -->
     <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/12.1.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>





</body>

</html>
```

here is the scripts.js page

```
  ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#body' ) )
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );

$(document).ready(function(){

    alert('hello');

});
```

not sure why nothing works from the scripts.js page. The alert is not working. I have JQuery.js referenced also..

Thank you

Comment: `script.js` needs to be included after the others, since it uses functionalities provided by them.

Comment: Thank you, so it is a good idea to have no javascript entries in the header, only in the footer?

Comment: I would put them inside `<head>`

Answer (score 1):

You should put `<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>` after JQuery and other dependencies. Because your script.js is using JQuery before you imported it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->    

     <!-- jQuery -->    
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

       <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

       <!-- WYSIWYG -->
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/12.1.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

        <!-- MY JS -->
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Just make the following changes in your footer and everything will work fine.

**Regarding to keep JS in header and footer**
`<script>`-tag over the closing `</body>-`Tag, this will prevent that the page is loading endless for the Javascript file, before the page is actually loaded.
It was trends before to put JavaScript code in the header but now because of SEO and site performance, it is better to put JavaScripts in the footer. yes, that means all the js code.

**How to avoid such issues in future?**
you first need to include the dependencies required by your code and other libraries. like jQuery is required by most of the libraries bootstraps, fancybox, jQuery full calendar and so on. so first include jQuery library then other js libraries if they have any other dependencies than include them before your custom javascript. it is just same as in your code you define something above. what if you try to use it before defining it? no way it will never work...

**Now what about CSS dependencies?**
always include them in the header inside  tags.